# Високосный год

Tags: этимология

Интересует этимология слова "високосный" — у меня нет идей, от какого слова оно может происходить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямое заимствование из латинского: *bis sextus* — "второй шестой".

По римской календарной традиции 24 февраля обозначалось как *ante diem sextum calendas martii* (шестой день перед мартовскими календами, т. е. шесть дней до марта).
Юлий Цезарь ввел календарь, позднее названный его именем, основным отличием которого была вставка дополнительного дня, этот день вставлялся после 24 февраля и обозначался как *ante diem bis sextus calendas martii* (если я ничего в падежах не напутал). Отсюда и "високосный" (от *bis sextus*).
Позднее календарь несколько изменился, но традиция вставлять "лишний" день именно в феврале осталась, этот день продолжали называть високосным, позднее название перешло и на сам *високосный год.*

Comment: не могу проследить в этом ответе происхождение слова "високосный"

Comment: Проследить-то можно, но тогда получается, что слово очень сильно исковеркали в процессе адаптации.

Comment: Да, исковеркали. такова судьба многих слов.

Answer (score 1):

Во времена Юлия Цезаря первый день каждого месяца называли «календами», седьмой – «нонами», а пятнадцатый – «идами».
28 февраля римляне называли «первым днем перед мартовскими календами» («primum dies ante calendas martias», primer día antes de las calendas de marzo), 27 февраля был «вторым днем до мартовских календ» («secundum dies ante calendas martias», segundo día antes de las calendas de marzo), 26 февраля – третьим днем, и т.д.
Для того чтобы ввести високосный год, Юлий Цезарь добавил один день между шестым и пятым днем перед календами, т.е. между днями 23 и 24 февраля. Этот дополнительный день был назван «вторым шестым днем до мартовских календ» – «bis sextus dies ante calendas martias», "segundo día sexto antes de las calendas de marzo", поэтому и год, когда добавлялся такой день, был назван «bissextus». Потом испанцы переиначили bissextus на bisiesto - которое переводится на русский как високосный. Но почему именно високосный называется високосным информации не нашел.

Comment: *Но почему именно високосный называется високосным информации не нашел.*  - а то, что вы процитировали, это разве не информация? O_o. непонятно, правда, при чем тут испанцы, ну это ладно.